# Set div width to 100% and fix it at that width

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div that fills up 100% of the screen, but when zoomed in, it continues to take up the original amount instead of shrinking to fit the new dimensions. Is there any way to do this? I can't show any code as I haven't tried anything

Comment: How do you know that it won't work if you haven't tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should add your own research before asking a question. SO Community generally do not accept these kind of questions. follow this link for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Hugh don't use percentages and try adding overflow: scroll to your div.

Comment: This is something that can't be done without JavaScript I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
<html>
      <body style="width:100%;">
        <div id="wideDiv" style="width:100%;background-color:lemonchiffon;height:20px;position:static;">
        Hope this helps!
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```